# How do I use arango dump tool?

Tags: arangodb

I'm new to using ArangoDB and I'm currently trying to use the arangodump tool in ArangoDB 2.5.5.  But I have no idea where to find it?

Do I run it using  the JSShell in the web interface? As when ever I try to run this command I get an unexpected identifier error.

```
arangodump --server.database PerformanceTest --output-directory "performanceTestDump"
```

I've checked that I'm using the correct database name and that the output-directory doesn't already exist.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK my bad, I needed to use the arangodump.exe in my install folder...

Comment: Right. The JSShell in the web interface is meant for executing JavaScript commands (which may include operations on collections and documents). The ArangoShell is a separate binary (`arangosh`) that does about the same, but does not run in the browser. `arangodump`, `arangorestore` and `arangoimp` are binaries for backing up, restoring or importing data resp. All the binaries should be placed in your installation folder.